# Video or Photo statistics

Tags: facebook, api, video, statistics

Is there any way to pickup stats for video or photo facebook object (not youtube videos shared on facebook)?

Stats like:
views
shares
likes

I've tried here: https://graph.facebook.com/817129783203 but with no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

M.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't access the number of photo/video views. However, in your case, likes may be accessed by querying:
https://graph.facebook.com/817129783203/likes.

Facebook Query Language (`FQL`) doesn't support `COUNT`, so you need to get likes number by counting the number of returned results (realized by an external method).